# How to append one dimensional arrays at axis=1

Tags: python, numpy

I am acquiring samples of dimensions (2,1). I am trying to stack them in columns.

I have tried the following:

```
# My initial state
state=np.array([2,3])
trajectory =state

# the following generate the next samples
class Buck:
  """ The following code simulates a Buck converter """
  def __init__(self,state,control):
    self.control=control
    self.state=state

  def Next_State(self):
    L, C = 1.0, 1.0
    R, G = 1.0, 1.0
    delta = 0.001


    Q = np.array([[-1.0/L,0.0],[0.0,1.0/C]])
    A = Q*np.matmul(Q,np.array([[R,1.0],[1.0,-G]]))

    next_state = state + delta*np.matmul(A,state)

    return next_state

# Here I am appending the new samples to trajectory

for i in range(100000):
  state=Buck.Next_State(state)
  np.append(trajectory,state,axis=1)
```

It is saying that I can not convert (2,) dimensional array to (2,2) dimensional array.

Comment: `np.vstack([trajectory,state])`?

Comment: Repeated np,.append is inefficient.  Collect values in a list, and do one stack at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state` needs to be a column vector for the multiplication to work.  It is currently just a 1D array.  You can either add in a singleton dimension, or make `state` a 2D array of a single row and transpose:

```
state=np.array([2,3])[:,None]
```

OR

```
state=np.array([[2,3]]).T
```

However, if it is your task to append all of the states to your trajectory, then you need to change two more things:

1. You need to make a fresh copy of the `state` to `trajectory`.  Right now, you are only providing a slice to it so modifying `trajectory` will also modify `state`.
2. `np.append` outputs the newly appended array.  You are not capturing the output of the method so you are actually not appending to anything.

Therefore:

```
# My initial state
import numpy as np

state=np.array([2,3])[:,None] # Change
trajectory =state.copy() # Change

# the following generate the next samples
class Buck:
  """ The following code simulates a Buck converter """
  def __init__(self,state,control):
    self.control=control
    self.state=state

  def Next_State(self):
    L, C = 1.0, 1.0
    R, G = 1.0, 1.0
    delta = 0.001


    Q = np.array([[-1.0/L,0.0],[0.0,1.0/C]])
    A = Q*np.matmul(Q,np.array([[R,1.0],[1.0,-G]]))

    next_state = state + delta*np.matmul(A,state)

    return next_state

# Here I am appending the new samples to trajectory

for i in range(100000):
  state=Buck.Next_State(state)
  trajectory = np.append(trajectory,state,axis=1) # Change
```